# change the style of menu, if it is selected, without php

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

how can i change the style of menu, if it is selected, without php?
i can do it by php

```
`<? if($_GET[id] == "this_menu") echo "style='color:red'"?>`
```

but i want to do it without php. is it possible? thanks

Comment: -1 because you say you don't want to use php, but you don't say with what you do want do that. JavaScript?

Comment: @Mendy if i don't say with what, it means, that it isn't important! just not php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (document.location.search.match(/[?&]id=this_menu([&.*])?$/)) {
    document.getElementById('yourId').setAttribute('style', 'color: red');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do that on client? if so, use JavaScript.

Comment: @Mendy es, of corse on client, but how can i verify the GET array via javascript?
and why the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

With JS

> document.getElementById(gup("param")).setAttribute('style', 'color: red');
>
> function gup( param ) 
>   {
>
> var name =
>   param.toLowerCase();
>   var regexS =
>   "[\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
>   var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
>   var tmpURL = window.location.href;
>   var results = egex.exec( tmpURL );
>   if( results == null ) 
>   {         // Try to find an
>   alternative value
>   if (typeof alternatives == "object")
>    {
>   if(typeof alternatives[name] !="undefined")
>    {
>     return alternatives[name];
>   }
>   }
>   return "";
>   } 
>   else 
>   {
>   return results[1];
>   } 
>   };

Answer (score 0):

it can be done easily done by javascript:

use something like this

**document.getElementById('myMenu').style.color='#f0f0f0';**